# Fetch response does not contain Authorization Header sent by Server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, curl, cors, fetch-api

I am building an application in which server authenticates client's token and generates an Application token for further use.

I use `curl` to make sure everything works fine.

```
curl -XPOST -v -H "X-ID-TOKEN:eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6ImIyYmRjZDkyNGZhNWI1ZThhYjkwNTQ3M2ZjZTYxMGU3MWU0MjJlNmQifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL3NlY3VyZXRva2VuLmdvb2dsZS5jb20vc3RhZ2luZy1wZW5ueXRyYWsiLCJuYW1lIjoiSGFyaXQgSGltYW5zaHUiLCJwaWN0dXJlIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9saDQuZ29vZ2xldXNlcmNvbnRlbnQuY29tLy1fbFhqMk9VbVRuZy9BQUFBQUFBQUFBS
S9BQUFBQUFBQUFDTS9YYU5jMTJadGV5OC9waG90by5qcGciLCJhdWQiOiJzdGFnaW5nLXBlbm55dHJhayIsImF1dGhfdGltZSI6MTUwMTczMTc2MSwidXNlcl9pZCI6InJ4WjZtb240MGhhN1J5SDVpSEFPSHkxN0hrbzEiLCJzdWIiOiJyeFo2bW9uNDBoYTdSeUg1aUhBT0h5MTdIa28xIiwiaWF0IjoxNTAxNzMxNzYyLCJleHAiOjE1MDE3MzUzNjIsImVtYWlsIjoiaGFyaXQuc3Vic2NyaXB0aW9uc0BnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJlbWFpbF92ZXJpZmllZCI6dHJ1ZSwiZmlyZWJhc
2UiOnsiaWRlbnRpdGllcyI6eyJnb29nbGUuY29tIjpbIjEwMDIxNjY5NjgzMjQ3MDQzMTUwNyJdLCJlbWFpbCI6WyJoYXJpdC5zdWJzY3JpcHRpb25zQGdtYWlsLmNvbSJdfSwic2lnbl9pbl9wcm92aWRlciI6Imdvb2dsZS5jb20ifX0.oWWug78iVJITZsJdA7npwjaG_CFnhQahwWCjnkz8Vi2famuTL61s8_Shx4oZVbKzju-L7ebEC4MSOvMc3HeEUwiwt9SunOo8JWfzwgpDbVzFTlnHu5OUeESssniXY4EyAF0uvI6jh1zoEz4SbPO-D87RXMNZYo69c6PFJVDYv--0sm4M7Ajmh7ynMmoEMH0pzjh-7l91yRguO5piQE9GQYwWe9-Jj8YlqWMnMa69M_jMrE14fMCB2mjoa9jJvZR1a-ao8LqO1U1FO64mzgf55yG8OS7aGVDN7gLxk1-RcqLxJogo0BDqsrdDykoeGHb1UflQP7dtazc47r3flELBGw" "http://loc
alhost:8080/login"
*   Trying ::1...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
> POST /login HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
> X-ID-TOKEN:eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6ImIyYmRjZDkyNGZhNWI1ZThhYjkwNTQ3M2ZjZTYxMGU3MWU0MjJlNmQifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL3NlY3VyZXRva2VuLmdvb2dsZS5jb20vc3RhZ2luZy1wZW5ueXRyYWsiLCJuYW1lIjoiSGFyaXQgSGltYW5zaHUiLCJwaWN0dXJlIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9saDQuZ29vZ2xldXNlcmNvbnRlbnQuY29tLy1fbFhqMk9VbVRuZy9BQUFBQUFBQUFBSS9BQUFBQUFBQUFDTS9YYU5jMTJadGV5OC9waG90by5qcGciLCJhdWQi
OiJzdGFnaW5nLXBlbm55dHJhayIsImF1dGhfdGltZSI6MTUwMTczMTc2MSwidXNlcl9pZCI6InJ4WjZtb240MGhhN1J5SDVpSEFPSHkxN0hrbzEiLCJzdWIiOiJyeFo2bW9uNDBoYTdSeUg1aUhBT0h5MTdIa28xIiwiaWF0IjoxNTAxNzMxNzYyLCJleHAiOjE1MDE3MzUzNjIsImVtYWlsIjoiaGFyaXQuc3Vic2NyaXB0aW9uc0BnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJlbWFpbF92ZXJpZmllZCI6dHJ1ZSwiZmlyZWJhc2UiOnsiaWRlbnRpdGllcyI6eyJnb29nbGUuY29tIjpbIjEwMDIxNjY5
NjgzMjQ3MDQzMTUwNyJdLCJlbWFpbCI6WyJoYXJpdC5zdWJzY3JpcHRpb25zQGdtYWlsLmNvbSJdfSwic2lnbl9pbl9wcm92aWRlciI6Imdvb2dsZS5jb20ifX0.oWWug78iVJITZsJdA7npwjaG_CFnhQahwWCjnkz8Vi2famuTL61s8_Shx4oZVbKzju-L7ebEC4MSOvMc3HeEUwiwt9SunOo8JWfzwgpDbVzFTlnHu5OUeESssniXY4EyAF0uvI6jh1zoEz4SbPO-D87RXMNZYo69c6PFJVDYv--0sm4M7Ajmh7ynMmoEMH0pzjh-7l91yRguO5piQE9GQYwWe9-Jj8YlqWMnMa69M_jMrE14fMCB2mjoa9jJvZR1a-ao8LqO1U1FO64mzgf55yG8OS7aGVDN7gLxk1-RcqLxJogo0BDqsrdDykoeGHb1UflQP7dtazc47r3flELBGw
>
< HTTP/1.1 200
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: 0
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: origin, content-type, accept, authorization, bearer, x-id-token
< Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD
< Access-Control-Max-Age: 1209600
< Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJyeFo2bW9uNDBoYTdSeUg1aUhBT0h5MTdIa28xIiwiZXhwIjoxNTAyNTgyNDAwfQ.o3aw_ozg813jga6TdCvtV1mMJngO6f4Wgy2dYm4G7O2G6LvYADzIafXJn0Wmvw8-f5scDcmTf6wT_zyMHIDFRg
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Thu, 03 Aug 2017 03:55:50 GMT
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

As you can see, the server sends back the `Authorization` header to the client.

On my `Javascript` application, my code to interact with server looks like

**Api.js**

```
let getAppToken = (idToken) => {
    return fetch("http://localhost:8080/login", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "X-ID-TOKEN": idToken
        }
    });
};

module.exports = {
    getAppToken: getAppToken,
};
```

Which is used in my `React` component as
**Login.js**

```
            console.log("idToken:", idToken);
            getAppToken(idToken)
                .then((response) => {
                    response.headers.forEach((val, key) => {
                        console.log(key, val)
                    });
                });
```

When I run this `React` application, the only headers I see are

```
cache-control no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
expires 0
pragma no-cache
```

Why don't I see the remaining headers sent by server? How can I fix this situation?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server must be configured to send an [`Access-Control-Expose-Headers` response header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers) that includes "`Authorization`" in its value if you want the browser to allow your requesting frontend JavaScript code to access the `Authorization` response header value.

If the response includes no value for the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` header, the only response headers that browsers will let you access from client-side JavaScript in your web app are `Cache-Control`,
`Content-Language`,
`Content-Type`,
`Expires`,
`Last-Modified`
and 
`Pragma`.

See https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-safelisted-response-header-name for the spec on that.